# Difference between мириться, смириться и примириться с чем-либо

Tags: глаголы

According to the dictionaries, all three of these verbs mean **to come to terms with a situation or fact** or **to resign oneself to something inevitable**. Are they interchangeable or are there any important nuances to be aware of?

Comment: According to the dictionaries, is this the only meaning for each of those? If so, you need better dictionaries. Seriously; no offense.

Comment: Мириться - to come to peace with smb after a war/fight/argument/etc . Смириться sounds like 'completely примириться' ('при-' for incomplete action, e.g. 'прикрыть дверь'), and примириться is like 'to resign oneself to something inevitable or impossible' but 'for a while now, to give oneself a better chance with cold mind, in the future'. I don't think it's a dictionary answer, but quick explanation how I feel the difference between these three, so just a comment. Not interchangeable.

Comment: @jwalker: maybe I didn't make myself clear. They all share the meanings given by me - AMONGST OTHER MEANINGS, but my concern is with their coinciding rendering of the meaning "to come to terms with something"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**`мириться`**](https://ru.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F), *imperfective*, (1) to get to peace or (2) to suffer, tolerate something that one does not have an opportunity to change/meliorate

> for the latter meaning: `*Он мирился с отсутствием горячей воды, но не с хамством уборщицы.` You can use `терпеть + Accusative` instead of `мириться с + Instrumental` here.

**`смириться`**, *perfective*, to stop fighting or resisting something, to refuse trying to change something, to get conformed

> `смириться со своим положением`,
>       `смириться со своим поражением`,
>       BTW, `смирение` (humility)

**`примириться`**, *perfective*, to get to reconciliation, on more equal terms with an opposing part than as with `смириться`

`смириться` / `примириться` may be opposed (with some exaggeration) as *to surrender / to find the way to deal with*.

see also Quassnoi’s answer

Answer (score 2):

"мириться с чем-либо"
временно быть согласным на существование чего-либо, но иметь надежду на изменение ситуации в будущем.

"смириться с чем-либо"
признать существование чего-либо как неизбежного факта без надежды на изменение в будущем.

"примириться с чем-либо"
полностью признать что-либо, принять другую точку зрения, быть согласным.

Answer (score 2):

*Смиряться* (meaning "come to terms with") is a Slavonicism which started to replace *примиряться* after 1940's.

[image]

It was occasionally used in Russian before 1940's (18 entries in the corpus against 669 for *примиряться*) but almost completely replaced *примиряться* by now in this meaning. Right now, *примиряться* mostly used in the meaning of "reconcile", with animate objects.

Before 1940's, *смиряться* was used mostly as an intransitive verb meaning to "to humble oneself".

Church Slavonic, on the other hand, used transitive *смиряться* extensively, meaning both "to come in terms with" and "to reconcile".

This passage from Elizabeth Bible in Church Slavonic:

> Аще ли же разлучится, да пребываетъ безбрачна, или да смирится съ мужемъ своимъ

reads in Synodal Russian translation as:

> Если же разведётся, то должна оставаться безбрачною, или примириться с мужем своим